# Problems with security and privacy with JNativeHook Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Hi I am using JNativeHook to add a global shortcut to an application that display a notification type jframe in the right hand corner of the screen. Currently my code in when run in Eclipse the program works perfectly fine. However after exporting to a runnable jar file the application crashed. After a few google searches I discovered I needed to add Jar Launcher to Accessibility part of the security pane in preferences.

However now I have a new problem. My program runs but does not accept my global shortcut (nothing happens when pressed). Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is the code I am using to add the JNativeHook and keybinds.

Main File:

```
    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new KeyManager());
```

KeyManager:

```
    private String periodName = new String();


@Override
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub







    if (arg0.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_5 && NativeInputEvent.getModifiersText(arg0.getModifiers()).equals(
            "Ctrl")) {
        Calendar setup = Calendar.getInstance();
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), setup.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0);
        GregorianCalendar[] timesM = {new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 9, 40, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),10, 30, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 55, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 20, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 12, 15, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 13, 15, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 14, 10, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 15, 05, 0), null};
        GregorianCalendar[] timesT = {new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 9, 30, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 10, 20, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 10, 35, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 00, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 50, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 12, 40, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 14, 15, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 15, 05, 0), null};
        GregorianCalendar[] timesW = {new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 9, 30, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 10, 20, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 10, 35, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 00, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 50, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 12, 40, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 14, 15, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 15, 05, 0), null};
        GregorianCalendar[] timesTh = {new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 9, 30, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 10, 20, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 10, 35, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 00, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 50, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 12, 40, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 14, 15, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 15, 05, 0), null};
        GregorianCalendar[] timesF = {new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 9, 35, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 10, 30, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 50, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 11, 15, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 12, 30, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 13, 25, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 14, 15, 0), new GregorianCalendar(setup.get(Calendar.MONTH), setup.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 15, 05, 0), null};
        System.out.println("Hour of day" + setup.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        GregorianCalendar[] a = null;


        System.out.println("Pressed");
        Calendar currentDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(currentDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        Boolean wasFound = false;
        switch (currentDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                a = timesM;
                a[8] = cal;
                System.out.println("Monday");
                System.out.println(a.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(cal.before(a[i]));

                    if (cal.before(a[i])) {
                        periodName = lincoln.getCurrentPeriod(0, i++);
                        System.out.println(periodName);

                        wasFound = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                a = timesT;
                a[8] = cal;
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (cal.before(a[i])) {
                        periodName = lincoln.getCurrentPeriod(0, i++);
                        System.out.println(periodName);

                        wasFound = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }
                break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                a = timesW;
                a[8] = cal;
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (cal.before(a[i])) {
                        periodName = lincoln.getCurrentPeriod(0, i++);
                        System.out.println(periodName);

                        wasFound = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                a = timesTh;
                a[8] = cal;
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (cal.before(a[i])) {
                        periodName = lincoln.getCurrentPeriod(0, i++);
                        System.out.println(periodName);

                        wasFound = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                a = timesF;
                a[8] = cal;
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (cal.before(a[i])) {
                        periodName = lincoln.getCurrentPeriod(0, i++);
                        System.out.println(periodName);

                        wasFound = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Weekends");
                periodName = "Weekends";

                break;







        }
        if (!wasFound || periodName == "Weekends") {

            Alert alert = new Alert("School is not currently on.", "Please check during a valid time.");
        }
        else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(periodName, "Yet to be added");

        }


    }


}

@Override
public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Finally Alert:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Works!");
        final Timer timer = new Timer(10000, this);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel(Title);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(information);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton btnDismiss = new JButton("Dismiss");
    btnDismiss.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            timer.stop();
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnDismiss, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

    frame.setLocation( (int) (ge.getMaximumWindowBounds().getWidth() -     frame.getWidth()), 25);

    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're abusing the event modifiers in new and interesting ways ;)  Try the following:

```
if (arg0.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_5 && arg0.getModifiers() & NativeInputEvent.CTRL_MASK) {
```

If you are using JNativeHook with Swing/AWT please read the [working with swing](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Examples#working-with-swing) wiki section for how to properly interact with it.

To address the accessibility issue; On OS X < 10.9, the accessibility check box needs to be checked in the system preferences.  In 10.9 and later, you must register each application requesting accessibility access independently.  Most of the time this will simply need to be the java runtime unless you are using a wrapper to start Java (like eclipse does).